# Show that $\exists m \in(k,\ell):f''(m)+f(m)=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be twice differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and $f'(x)\not=0$, $f'(k)=f(\ell)$ and $f'(\ell)=f(k)$. Show that $\exists m \in(k,\ell):f''(m)+f(m)=0$.

The only thing that I was able to do is to show that $\exists n \in (k,\ell):f'(n)-f(n)=0$. I'd like a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider
$$
h(x)=(f(x))^2+(f'(x))^2
$$
and see what the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) implies.

Comment: thanks for the hint

Comment: @mxaxc Did you work it out? Feel free to post your own answer if you want more feedback.

Comment: could you show your process of finding $h$?

Comment: @M.Van There was no much algorithmic construction behind, just a trial to bind together $f'$ and $f''+f$.

Comment: @Α.Γ. I was able to solve it, using Rolle's theorem for $h$

Comment: @mxaxc Yes, it works too.